# How can I attach events to cloned / dynamically generated elements?

Tags: jquery, clone

http://www.stableflow.com/downloads/jquery-plugins/360-degrees-product-view/

found this script. How might I attach events to individual images here. For example, if I wanted a custom click on image 10 and a hover on image 20.

Comment: [Reading through the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/) might be a good place to start

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically generated elements, consider using `live(event, function)` method or newer one - `on(event, function)`.

So if your plugin generates some DOM logic, consider attaching events using on on them, and as they will be ready, they will have events attached.

Logic would be like this:

```
...
...
//attach events
$('image:eq(10)').on('click', function() {
//my custom click handler for 10th image
});
...
...
```

Initialize some plugin which will construct DOM logic around/or using your images